Cannot get PyTesseract to Identify Numbers within Boxes, how do I make it more accurate?
Here is my code
My code is analysing sections of scanned pdf that tries to pick out digits. These digits are on a white background within a black square.
It identifies some others well, like 1.6.

It repeatedly attributes it as 4.4 not 1.1!
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Convert PDF pages to images
pages = convert_from_path(r'C:\Users....\test.pdf', 400, poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-24.07.0\Library\bin')

for page_num, page in enumerate(pages):

    if 0 <= page_num <= 6:  
        page_cv = np.array(page)  
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(page_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        height, width = thresh.shape[:2]
        
        # Calculate the width of the first third
        fifth_width = width // 5
        
        cropped_image = thresh[:, :fifth_width]

        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_image, config='digits --psm 11')
        print(f"From page {page_num}")
        print(text)

        debug_image_path = f"debug_page_{page_num + 1}.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(debug_image_path, cropped_image)

I tried using findcountours to identify the boxes then only look in them, but this had the same error.

Do you have any suggestions for OCR engines that may work better? Thanks
